# Pass multiple parameters with angularjs $location.path

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to pass two parameters via view > controller 1 > $route > controller 2.

from view 1:

```
<td><a href="" ng-class="getGroups({{acnOrgId}}, {{row.NetworkOrgID}})">{{row.NetworkOrgFullName}}</a></td>
```

from controller 1:

```
    $scope.getGroups = function (acnId, orgId) {
    $location.path('/Groups/' + acnId +'/'+ orgId);
}
```

from my routeProvider:

```
    $routeProvider.when('/Groups/:acnId/:orgId', {
    templateUrl: 'Pages/acn/partials/groups.html',
    controller: 'groupsController'
});
```

On my controller 2:

```
 console.log($routeParams.acnId ,  $routeParams.orgId)
```

My results in Console.Log are:  [object Object] 164

I can do this with a single param and I actually pass the id I want to pass.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the [edit] link at the bottom left instead of adding these kinds of comments.

Comment: Thanks ryanyuyu. Done.

Comment: Have a Look at ui-Router. It handles the routing as states and has this functionality built in (ui-sref directive). It also allows you to refactor your URI's much more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Your ng-class should be using `{{}}` interpolation directive, I don't understand why you used `ng-class`

```
ng-class="getGroups(row.acnOrgId, row.NetworkOrgID)"
```

You redirecting purpose you could use anchor `ng-href` to create an href link.

```
<td>
   <a ng-href="/Groups/{{row.acnOrgId+'/'+row.NetworkOrgID}}">{{row.NetworkOrgFullName}}</a>
</td>
```

Comment: That's embarrassing. That was supposed to be ng-click directive. Thanks Pankaj!

Comment: @crowsfeet why you wanted to do it from `ng-click`? any reason?

Comment: I'm passing those params to a function. What would you suggest?

Comment: That was meant to be an ng-click directive that passed two params. It was a typo. But you are right, I could just as easily use the herf. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @crowsfeet check that..if it works then do accept answer..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are problems with the link tag and the use of service $ location.

There are two possible ways to switch from view 1 to 2:

by using `ng-href`: `<a ng-href="/Groups/{{row.acnOrgId}}/{{row.NetworkOrgID}}">{{row.NetworkOrgFullName}}</a>`

by using `ng-click`: `<a href="" ng-click="getGroups(acnOrgId, row.NetworkOrgID)">{{row.NetworkOrgFullName}}</a>`

About `getGroups` function. Consider that [$location.path](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#path) change the router to the URL passed as a parameter.